# How to Debug this : Canonical String should have been from signed Api Gateway request

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

What is a way to debug this error ? I am trying to call api gateway that has a resource policy with IAM role.

```
The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/Prod/creeks/finbi_ldap
group_name=AWS-FINBI-APPS&login=bonneyv
content-length:
content-type:application/json
host:ipcd849p1c.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20210409T052446Z
x-amz-security-token:IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBUaCXVzLWVhc3QtM6w==

content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'
```

Here is how I am signing the request ?

```
const headers = originalRequest.data === undefined ? {} :
        {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

const requestToBeSigned = {
        body: JSON.stringify(originalRequest.data),
        headers: Object.assign(headers, originalRequest.headers),
        host: apiUrl.host,
        method: originalRequest.method || 'GET',
        path: `${apiUrl.pathname}${originalRequest.path || '/'}`,
    };
const accessKeyId: string | undefined = credentials.accessKeyId;
const secretAccessKey: string = credentials.secretAccessKey;
const sessionToken: string | undefined = credentials.sessionToken;

return aws4.sign(requestToBeSigned, {
            accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey,
            sessionToken
        });
```

I don't see any method to see what the request I send was other than what I see on browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these errors just terrible to debug.
Here is what finally works for me in the signing.

1. Know whether to include `body`
2. Sort the `body`
3. Build a `queryString`
4. Know whether to include `queryString`

```
const headers = originalRequest.data === undefined ? {} : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    const path = `${apiUrl.pathname}`;
    const method = originalRequest.method || 'GET';
    const isPost = originalRequest.method === 'POST';
    const requesting = isPost ? originalRequest.data : originalRequest.params;
    const sortedBody = isPost ? sortRequestData(requesting) : requesting;
    const queryString = buildQueryString(sortedBody);

    const requestOptions = {
        body: isPost ? JSON.stringify(sortedBody) : '',
        data: isPost ? sortedBody : null,
        headers: headers,
        host: apiUrl.host,
        method: method,
        path: !isPost ? `${path}${queryString}` : `${path}`,
        params: isPost ? null : requesting,
    };
```

```
const buildQueryString = (obj: any) => {
    // If input is not a key value store
    if (!obj || Object.entries(obj).length === 0 || obj.constructor !== Object) {
        return ''
    }
    return '?' + Object.entries(obj)
        .map(([key, val]) => `${key}=${val}`)
        .join('&')
};
```

```
const sortRequestData = (obj: any) => {
    // If input is not a key value store
    if (!obj || Object.entries(obj).length === 0 || obj.constructor !== Object) {
        return ''
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.sort();
    let sortedObj: any = {};
    keys.forEach((k: string) => sortedObj[k] = obj[k]);
    return sortedObj
};
```